# Swift: Can't seem to access objects in nested array

Tags: swift3

I am testing my feet in Swift and am trying to access certain objects which are part of a nested array.

The structure of the `array` looks something like this:

```
[ "Title": "Book Title", "Type": "Fiction", "Chapters": [
{"Title": "Chapter 1 Title", "Content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", "Keyword": "foo"}, 
{"Title": "Chapter 3 Title", "Content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", "Keyword": "foo"}, 
{"Title": "Chapter 5 Title", "Content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", "Keyword": "foo"}, 
...
], 
[ "Title": "Book Title", "Type": "Fiction", "Chapters": [
{"Title": "Chapter 2 Title", "Content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", "Keyword": "foo"}, 
{"Title": "Chapter 3 Title", "Content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", "Keyword": "foo"}
], 
...]
```

The array is loaded from a plist file and is loaded something like this:

```
var myArr: Array<Any>
myArr = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!) as! [Dictionary<String, Any>]
```

I am having difficulty accessing specific children of the chapters array.

```
let bookNum = 1
let chapNum = 3

let s: Dictionary = myArr[bookNum] as! Dictionary<String, Any>
if let s1 = (s["Chapters"] as AnyObject)[chapNum] {

  if let obj = s1 as! Dictionary<String, Any> {
    print("/(obj["Title"])")
  }

}
```

I get the error, that "Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not Dictionary".
In general I am getting the feeling that I am not doing this correctly. The problem is, that the exact structure of the array is not known. Theoretically a Book could be listed without chapters.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Are you using structs for your model, e.g a struct for `Book` and `Chapter` ?

Comment: No - not consciously. ;) I just loaded the plist into an array and wanted to traverse it. Would it be better to load everything into structs?

Comment: I think that would be better, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already specified the `myArr` type as `[Dictionary<String, Any>]`, so there is no need to explicitly specify the type of `s` because if you access object from `myArr` it should only dictionary nothing else.

```
let s = myArr[bookNum]
```

Now `Chapters` is also Array of dictionary so you need to type cast it that and then access the chapter according to you want.

```
if let chapters = s["Chapters"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] {// OR [[String:Any]]
    if chapNum < chapters.count {
        print(chapters[chapNum]["Title"])
    }
}
```